# Sending Objects over TCP and update Textfields using the object values

Tags: java, swing, tcp, serversocket, event-dispatch-thread

I have a TCP Client-Server program in Java using GUI. The idea is to get the values from the textfields on the Server program, store it in an object and send it to the Client side. The Client side deserializes the object and updates the textfields with the values from the deserialized object.

ChattingServer.java

```
public class ChattingServer extends JFrame {

private JTextField senddata;
private JTextField packettype;
private JTextField packetsize;
private JTextField offset;
private JButton sendButton;
private JButton startServer;
private TCPServer mServer;
private TCP_DATA_PACKET TDP;

sendButton = new JButton("Update");
    sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TDP.bSendRequestedData = senddata.getText().toString();
            TDP.uPacketType = packettype.getText().toString();
            TDP.uPacketSize = packetsize.getText().toString();
            TDP.uOffset = offset.getText().toString();
            mServer.SendObject(TDP);                
        }
    });

    startServer = new JButton("Start");
    startServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
           startServer.setEnabled(false);               
           try{
                IP.setText(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
           } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
           }
           mServer = new TCPServer();
           mServer.start();
        }
    });
public class TCPServer extends Thread{
    public TCP_DATA_PACKET packet;
    public final int SERVERPORT = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
    private ObjectOutputStream mOut;


    public void SendObject(Object obj){
        try{
          mOut.writeObject(this);
          System.out.println("Object sent successfully!");
          mOut.flush();
          mOut.close();

          }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe);  
          }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")

    public void run() {
        super.run();

        try {
            System.out.println("S: Connecting...");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            System.out.println("Server ip:" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println(client.getRemoteSocketAddress()+" connected\n");
            ClientIP.setText(client.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
            System.out.println("S: Receiving...");

            try {
                mOut = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("S: Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                client.close();
                System.out.println("S: Done.");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("S: Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

ChattingClient.java is just the same but only receives objects

```
public class TCPServer extends Thread{
    public TCP_DATA_PACKET packet = null;
    public final int SERVERPORT = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
    public final String SERVERADD = IP.getText().toString();
    public boolean running = false;

    public void run(){
        super.run();
        running = true;

        try {
            System.out.println("S: Connecting...");
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERADD);
            Socket client = new Socket(serverAddr,SERVERPORT);
            try {
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                while (running) {
                    packet = (TCP_DATA_PACKET)in.readObject();

                    if (packet!= null) {
                        senddata.setText(packet.bSendRequestedData);
                        packettype.setText(packet.uPacketType);
                        packetsize.setText(packet.uPacketSize);
                        offset.setText(packet.uOffset);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("S: Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                client.close();
                System.out.println("S: Done.");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("S: Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

However, I am getting NullPointer Exception on the server side.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ChattingServer$1.actionPerformed(ChattingServer.java:81)
```

at

```
TDP.bSendRequestedData = senddata.getText().toString();
```

in

```
sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TDP.bSendRequestedData = senddata.getText().toString();
            TDP.uPacketType = packettype.getText().toString();
            TDP.uPacketSize = packetsize.getText().toString();
            TDP.uOffset = offset.getText().toString();
            mServer.SendObject(TDP);                
        }
    });
```

and EOF Exception on Client side at

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
```

Im stuck here... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

EDIT: Fixed the NullPointerException by initializing the object TDP:

```
TCP_DATA_PACKET TDP = new TCP_DATA_PACKET();
```

in both the Client and the Server. Now, im getting this exception on the Server side

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

and the same EOF Exception on the Client side

```
java.io.EOFException

at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at ChattingClient$TCPServer.run(ChattingClient.java:132)
```

Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong here?? Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Why don't you initialise your `private JTextField senddata;` at declaration? It would resolve this problem (but you may still have more)

Comment: how do you initialize senddata? it's probably null

Comment: I dint initialize any of the textfields. After tcp connection is established, I give some values in the textfields and click the "update" button. It is supposed to take those values and send it to the Client. But it is throwing NullPointerException. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here??

Comment: Can you show how the TCPServer threads are being initialised and run? Are they being run in a loop or just one time? Because it seems that your server is not waiting for the client to receive the object before closing the stream. And your client tries to receive the object when the server stream is already closed.

Comment: the Server thread is initialised and run in the startServer button, only once. What do you mean by keeping them in a loop?